# PHP Last Array Key Issue

Tags: php

I have this simple code for pasting images from a directory, I've sorted them into an array but the problem I can't seem to work out is how to get the last array to be different.

**This is my code so far:**

```
foreach($images as $image){
echo("{image : '$image'}, ");
}
```

I'm looking to keep print the single items in the array but on the **last** one I'd like to **not have the comma**.

Any help would be great,

Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to make the string in json format? If so, use json_encode: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple.

```
function doit($image) {
    return "{image: '$image'}"
}

$images = array_map('doit',$images);
$images = implode(', ',$images);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
echo "{image : '".implode("'}, {image : '",$images)."'}";
```

Comment: It's all in the eye of the beholder ;). It isn't for me, but if it's confusing to you, it may also be for others, in which case this would be a bad solution.

Comment: I mean i see why it works. it is just confusing to understand at first glance.

Comment: Actually it looks efficient. In lieu of just using the more appropriate json_encode this is the advisable replacement. (Could be made more readable with some whitespace though.)

Comment: Ack, that's what I thought you meant, but first glance also counts. When coding / debugging someone's code most of it should be blindingly obvious. Nothing as irritating as reading obtuse one-liners which halt your work temporarily. Even more irritating if it turns about to be something you've written yourself some time ago :P.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
<?php
$buffer = array();
foreach($images as $image){
    $buffer[] = "{image : '$image'}";
}
echo implode(', ', $buffer);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the key and the length of the array:

```
$arrLength = count($images);
foreach($images as $key=>$image){
   echo("{image : '$image'}");
   if($key < $arrLength - 1){  echo ", "; }
}
```

Or use an [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php):

```
function make_array($n)
{
    return "{image: '$n'}"
}

$map = array_map("make_array", $images);
$new_array = implode(', ', $map);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this attractively with a `do..while` loop:

```
$image = current($images);
do {
    echo "{image : '$image'}";
} while (($image = next($images) && (print " ,"));
```

Note that you have to use `print` not `echo` there, as `echo` does not behave as a function.

The second part of the conditional only executes if the first part passes, so `" ,"` will only be printed if another image exists.

---

If there is the possibility (as in, even the vaguest *possibility*) that your array may contain values that aren't non-empty strings, you'll need to be more verbose:

```
} while (
    (false !== ($image = next($images)) && 
    (print " ,")
);
```

I'm not convinced this is very readable, however, even split over multiple lines, so if this is the case I'd go for one of the other approaches.

Answer (score 0):

Either use an if statement and check if it's the last and echo accordingly, or concatenate without echoing, trim the result after it's generated, and echo.

Answer (score 0):

You could do if and else statements, where if its the last image print without comma else if it isn't print with comma.

Answer (score 0):

```
$last = array_pop(array_keys($images));

foreach($images as $key => $image) {
   if ($key == $last) {
      ... last image ,don't output comma
   }
}
```